# Deux sens de "Si vous vouliez travailler, vous seriez excellent !"

Tags: conditionnel

Bonjour,

> Le conditionnel peut indiquer :
>
> La possibilité (le locuteur considère au moment où il parle qu'une
> chose est possible) : *Si vous **vouliez** travailler, vous **seriez**
> excellent !* ([Les valeurs du conditionnel](https://www.ralentirtravaux.com/lettres/cours/conjugaison/valeur_conditionnel.php))

Mais cette même phrase peut signifier l'irréel :

*Si vous vouliez travailler* = ce n'est pas le cas : dans les faits, vous ne souhaitez pas travailler.

*Vous seriez excellent* = vous ne l'êtes pas à présent

Pourquoi ce site ne mentionne-t-il pas le deuxième sens de cette phrase ? Lorsque vous voyez cette phrase, comment choisissez-vous entre les deux possibilités d'interprétation, selon le contexte ?

Comment: Un détail mais dans l'exemple sur le site, _vouliez_ n'est pas souligné, n'étant pas le verbe au conditionnel...

Comment: @Amande Adorable Je sais, je l'ai souligné pour faciliter la compréhension, ces deux verbes étant liés. Oui, _vouliez_ n'est pas au conditionnel.

Comment: « *Vous seriez excellent* **≠** Vous ***ne*** l'êtes ***pas*** à présent » ; Non, pas de solution unique, on peut être excellent dans un domaine et ne pas chercher de travail dans l'emploi proposé (énoncé dans le passé par *vouliez*). Le conditionnel laisse le choix à la personne qui répond de changer d'avis maintenant, utiliser le présent, serait mettre une emprise/forcer la main sur cette dernière pour qu'elle accepte.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you're getting the semantics described here. The conditional by definition is *irrealis*. But that seems to be what their description says: « une chose est *possible* » ; that is, not *actual*.

The use of the conditional in this sentence *does* indeed, as you said, indicate that the person does not want to work right now.

Here's another example that shows how the conditional is used to prove a negative:

> S'il y avait des extraterrestres, on les aurait vus avant ce moment. Donc, il n'y en a pas.

Generally, the conditional half of this imparfait/conditional pairing is assumed *not* to be true, pragmatically speaking. This is also so in English. "If you lived here, you'd be home by now!" i.e., you are not home.

There is at least one other use of the conditional where this doesn't hold. I'm thinking of the polite one: « Voudriez-vous m'accompagner ? » Here, we read that it's not only possible but also hopefully true that the addressee wants to accompany the speaker. But this I wouldn't say is a semantic conditional, only a grammatical one.

Comment: Merci, mais si on veut parler d'une **possibilité**, pourquoi ne pas employer le présent ? Par exemple, _Si vous vous impliquez, vous serez (seriez) excellent_ ? C'est plus simple, non ? À moins que l'on n'emploie l'imparfait pour être plus poli ? Lorsque je vois _Si vous **vouliez** travailler, vous **seriez** excellent !_, je ne l'interprète comme une possibilité (peut-être à tort ?), je ne vois ici qu'une condition irréele au présent. Désolée, je fais pas mal de fautes lorsque j'écris en anglais, j'ai donc écrit mon commentaire en français.

Comment: _The use of the conditional in this sentence does indeed, as you said, indicate that the person does not want to work right now._ D'accord. Mais je ne parlerais alors pas d'une **possibilité**. Quoique... si cette personne se met à travailler après avoir entendu cette phrase...

Comment: @Oreste Selon la logique du conditionnel, il faut supposer, il faut prendre pour hypothèse quelque chose qui n'est pas vrai. (Ici il s'agit plus de la linguistique en général que du français en particulier.) Alors, tout ce qui n'est pas vrai peut être considéré comme possible, afin de parler des conséquences logiques. ...

Comment: C'est-à-dire que nous avons ici la structure « antécédent → conséquence » ; exprimer cette relation n'implique ni l'affirmation de l'antécédent, ni celle de la conséquence. Si on parle de façon technique. En plus on peut employer cette structure dans le cas où l'antécédent est vrai : « S'il est parti à 15h, certainement qu'il est chez lui maintenant » mais aussi dans le cas où l'antécédent est faux : « Si vous travailliez plus, vous gagneriez plus d'argent. » Notons qu'on a tendance à utiliser le conditionnel pour ce dernier cas.

Comment: Néanmoins, ce que vous dites est vrai : on peut dire à la place « Si vous voulez travailler, vous serez excellent. » Mais on peut pas utiliser le présent avec le conditionnel. Cela n'est pas de la sémantique, c'est simplement la concordance des temps, une règle assez arbitraire dans ce cas. On peut dire peut-être que la forme avec présent → futur est un peu « lax », elle n'a pas vraiment du sens (on dirait que futur → futur a plus de sens), mais n'empêche qu'elle est tout à fait courante et facile à comprendre.